Whenever I am trying to search for anything under dev tools my search is stuck at "indexing.." with a stop button beside it
This used to work earlier but now if I go to dev tools -> sources and perform a "search in all files" search it gets stuck with a loading bar and a stop button and I am unable to search anything in order to debug stuff. This same thing works fine for other google profile but unfortunately I need to use this particular profile for debugging. Can anyone help with this. Attaching a screenshot below:
I tried clearing cache and looked for other related articles but did not find any relevant article. I found an article saying clearing browser history worked but it is inconsistent as another time it did not work for the same user. I have some important data because of which I may not be able to try this out.
